# Not able to connect to Network drive through EC2

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to connect to a network drive through EC2. I have used the below python script to extract data from the network drive. But it is throwing error as FileNotFoundError:No Such file in Directory.

```
import os
import boto3

s3=boto3.client('s3')
data_folder=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'path of network drive')

for file in os.listdir(data_folder):
     s3.upload_file(os.path.join(data_folder,file),'s3 bucket',file)
```

Is there any method to connect network drive from EC2 or any AWS services?

Comment: Debug your code. Start with `data_folder` and then `os.path.join(data_folder,file)`. What do they evaluate to? Does that folder and file exist?

Comment: That folder is network drive. Through EC2  the code is not able to connect it due VPC or any other problem.

Comment: The Python code here is probably irrelevant. Do you have some mechanism for attaching and mounting the remote drive? Does this mechanism work? From the EC2 instance, can you list folders and files on the relevant mount point *after* this drive has been mounted on the EC2 instance?

Comment: No I dont know how to mount on EC2 server .

Comment: If I mount the network drive in local and run the code in cmd ,then it is working,but it is a very slow process.Using EC2 would make it fast and reliable as I have huge number of files in the network drive.

Comment: OK, so what's preventing you mounting the drive from EC2? You have provided zero information about what the remote drive is, how you are trying to mount it, or how that process fails.

Comment: It is a shared drive ,it contains folders and files which I need to migrate to s3 .The volume is huge so I am trying use EC2.I dont have much idea if I can mount the drive on EC2.If you know please help.

Comment: You still haven't provided much info about this drive. What is it? Where is it? How do you currently connect to it from your laptop or other machine? You may also want to look at [AWS Import/Export](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/send-us-that-data/) depending on your use case.

Comment: I have mentioned it clearly, it is a "Network Drive". I can access it using a path or the IP of the drive. But I am not able to access it through EC2.

Comment: OK if you're not going to explain in more detail I'm going to guess that it's an SMB share, or maybe CIFS. Find a suitable SMB/CIFS client for whatever operating system you are running on EC2  (which you also didn't explain btw).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make some assumptions that:

- You have a computer on a corporate network
- The computer can access a network drive on the corporate network
- You can to copy files from the network drive to an Amazon S3 bucket

If this is the case, then you can use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 sync` command to copy files from the computer to the Amazon S3 bucket.

If this is *not* the case, please Edit your question to provide more information.

Comment: Yes ,your assumption is right and the solution you shared (AWS CLI) is also right. But the speed of migration will be very slow as we have huge volume of data to migrate to s3.

Comment: The AWS CLI can upload files in parallel. You can [edit the configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-config.html) to optimise for available bandwidth. However, your main limiting factor will be the bandwidth you have between your corporate network and the Internet.

Comment: If you have a "huge" volume of data (eg 10s of TB), you might want to use [AWS Snowball](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/snowball/latest/ug/whatissnowball.html) to send data to Amazon S3. It is a physical storage device that is shipped to your location. You can then copy data to it and send it back to AWS.

Comment: We cant use AWS snowball as of now. I am trying to mount the drive on ec2.Below is the link which I am following.https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/samba-windows-linux .

Comment: Do you have a Direct Connect connection between your corporate network and AWS? If not, I would advise that you do not attempt to mount a network drive from your corporate network to an Amazon EC2 instance. The performance would be quite poor.